# How to use QThreadPool

Tags: multithreading, qt

I'm trying out a sample involving QThreadPool to improve performance instead of QThread. Below is my sample source code.

MyTask.cpp

```
class MyTask : public QObject, public QRunnable {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyTask(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

    void run() override {
        qDebug() << "create new thread";
    }

signals:
};
```

Controller.cpp

```
class Controller : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Controller(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

public slots:
    void request() {
        // Tạo MyTask trong thread chính hoặc thread quản lý GUI
        MyTask* task = new MyTask(this);

        // Đưa MyTask vào QThreadPool để thực hiện
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(task);
    }
};
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Controller* m_controller = new Controller();

    QTimer timer;
    timer.setInterval(1000 / FPS);
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, m_controller, &Controller::request);
    timer.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

However, I got the error as below.

```
ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread. Current thread 0x0x26cfee9ebc0. Receiver '' (of type 'Controller') was created in thread 0x0x26ce78368b0"
```

I'm not understanding what's going on. Is there anyone out there who can help me with this problem and does it matter if I use signals/slots here?

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for your respond. Is there any problem if my MyTask inherits QObject?

Comment: Change `new MyTask(this)` to `new MyTask()`

Comment: Also read https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#thread-affinity

Comment: A QObject belongs to the same thread as the parent so MyTask belongs to the main thread if you pass this as parent. But since it is a runnable, it is executed in another thread, which is why Qt warns you that there may be problems.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for your help. so if my MyTask inherits QObject is it possible to use signals/slots as usual?
Previously MyTask inherited QThread and QObject so signals/slots were no problem.

Comment: @KaiAkiho Inheriting from QThread *and* QObject doesn't make any sense, since QThread already inherits from QObject. Why have you switched to QRunnable?

Comment: @eyllanesc Because my problem calls this function many times like above, I often use QThreadPool+QRunable instead of QThread. so I just switched to QRunable

Comment: @KaiAkiho (please use `@username` more carefully) It seems like you want to use QThreadPool just to simplify thread management, but you also need the signal/slot mechanism in order to actually use such management correctly. AFAIK, QRunnable is not intended for such usage, being it a higher level (and much simpler) class. I don't know much about C++, but with python bindings it's common to create a "proxy QObject" for each QRunnable instance; still, that may not be a proper choice in C++, and a better QThread management (using custom worker queues) is probably a more appropriate approach.

Comment: @musicamante Do I need to manage MyTask* tasks? I understand that the system will automatically revoke.